# p11-kit: couldn't load module

Tags: debian

this error happend when i use apt-get update or when i want to update my git repos with https address.

```
p11-kit: couldn’t load module: /usr/lib/x8664-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: 
/usr/lib/x8664-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: 

cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ``/usr/lib/x8664-linux-gnu`` is not a valid library path. What OS + desktop environment (if any) are you running and what version of p11-kit do you have installed?

Comment: Debian(tag!) sid, mate-desktop, "apt-cache policy p11-kit 
p11-kit:
  Installed: 0.12-3
"